# My weather indicator resets on startup

Tags: indicator, weather

This window pops up on startup, and my configuration is gone:

[image: my-weather-indicator Preferences window]

How can I fix this? I think the problem started when I began using a different IP, but it may be something else.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but didn't work.

The appication is launched on startup like this: /usr/share/my-weather-indicator/my-weather-indicator.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was fixed. Please update and upgrade